# How to minimize a maximum of a function of 2 parameters with Pyhton

Tags: optimization

I calculate a distance between each point $c(x,y)$ and each point of $p(x,y)$. I need to find maximum among minimums of function:

```py
    def func(p,c):
        return math.sqrt((p[0] - c[0]) ** 2 + (p[1] - c[1]) ** 2)
```

where p and c can be presented as lists

```py
 p = [[1,2],[2,2], and so on]
 c = [[2,2],[3,3], and so on]
```

In other word, I need to find combinations of values among each p point and each c point that give me minimum of function. The problem that minimum of particulate point can cause increase of biggest minimum among all point. For example:

```py
p = [[1,1],[2,2]]
c = [[2,2],[3,3]]
```

Here if we take smallest minimum for point $c(2,2)$ in $p(2,2)$ overall minimum will increase cause for point $c(3,3)$ we only have point $p(1,1)$ thus we need to take $p(1,1)$ for point $c(2,2)$ and $p(2,2)$ for point $c(3,3)$

How can I do it in python?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me how this question relates to statistics. This might be a better fit on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looks like you could calculate the matrix of all pairwise distances, and pass it to [scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) to let it find the optimal solution.

Comment: Your function `func` is already defined in the python standard library under the name `math.dist`. Or you could use [sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer after better understanding the question:**

If the lengths of $p$ and $c$ are both $N$, there will be $N$ distances to calculate for any possible solution. I think you will need to calculate $N!$ sets of $N$ distances to make sure you've found the absolute smallest set of $N$ distances possible.

```py
from math import sqrt
import itertools

def dist(p, c):
    return sqrt((p[0] - c[0])**2 + (p[1] - c[1])**2)

def all_dist(p_list, c_list):
    all_dists = list()
    for i in range(len(p_list)):
        ith_dist = dist(p_list[i], c_list[i])
        all_dists.append(ith_dist)
    return(all_dists)

p_list = [[1, 0], [3, 3]]
c_list = [[3, 3], [4, 0]]

# Keep c fixed and check all the different permutations of p
N = len(p_list)
p_indices = list(itertools.permutations(range(N)))

all_possible_distance_maxes = list()
for order in p_indices:
    sorted_p = [p_list[index] for index in order]
    all_dists = all_dist(sorted_p, c_list)
    max_distances = max(all_dists)
    all_possible_distance_maxes.append(max_distances)
print(all_possible_distance_maxes)

min_index = all_possible_distance_maxes.index(min(all_possible_distance_maxes))

best_sorted_p = [p_list[index] for index in p_indices[min_index]]

# These two are now sorted to give the smallest maximum pair of distances
print(best_sorted_p)
print(c_list)
```

Output re-sorts `p_list` to `[[3, 3], [1, 0]]` as the max distance in that configuration (`1,0 to 4,0`) is smaller than the max distance of all other possible configurations (`1,0 to 3,3`)

Comment: not exactly, for each connection of points from p and c we have a distance and we need to connect them in such way that maximum distance between two connected points will be minimized, Example - [1,1] connects with [2,2] and [2,2] connects with [3,3] - two distance between these points equals sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = 1,41 and sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = 1,41 respectively but if we connect [2,2] with [2,2] and [1,1] with [3,3] we got sqrt(0^2 + 0^2) and sqrt(2^2 + 2^2) = 2.83.

Comment: Thus we got bigger distance in second case and we need a way to connect all of them to get minimum upper bound for all distances. In other word, minimize maximum distance

Comment: @Ivan Ah, I see. I've updated my answer - I think it matches what you're looking for now.

Comment: thank you for your solution.